# Using Twig Extension in base layout at Symfony 3

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I have a controller for setup a few things stored in DB. Pretty much the controller looks like:

```
class SetupController extends Controller
{   
    protected $foreground = '#fff';
    protected $background = '#333';
    protected $logo = 'default.png';
    protected $show_logo = true;

    public function HomePageAction()
    {
        ...          
        $options = [
            ...
            'logo'              => $this->logo,
            'foreground'        => $this->foreground,
            'background'        => $this->background
        ];

        return $this->render('CommonBundle:Layout:topbar_info.html.twig', ['options' => $options]);
    }
}
```

How I am using that function in `/app/Resources/views/base.html.twig` (this is my layout) as follow:

```
<head>
    ...
    {% block stylesheets %}
        ...
        <style type="text/css" media="all">
            .background, .dynamic_color {
                background-color: {{ options.background }};
            }    
        </style>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logo_id_area_container" class="topbar">
        {{ render(controller('CommonBundle:Setup:HomePage')) }}
    </div>
</body>
```

When I try to render the page it fails with the following error:

> Variable "options" does not exist.

Of course where I am trying to use the var it doesn't exist because is coming out on the `CommonBundle:Setup:HomePage` action, <strike>does any one knows a better way to achieve this?</strike>

After some research I come up with the use of a Twig Extension but I am missing something since is not working as I expect. My Twig Extension code looks like the one above:

```
class SetupExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    use MMISessionTools;

    protected $em, $session, $zend, $session_record, $storage;
    protected $foreground = '#fff', $background = '#333', $logo = 'default.png', $show_logo = true;

    public function __construct(
        RegistryInterface $em,
        SessionInterface $session,
        ZendBridge $zb,
    ) {
        $this->em      = $em;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->zend    = $zb;

        // Start the session before lookup for the required data
        $session->start();

        // Vars for internal usage
        $this->session_record = $record = $em->getRepository('CommonBundle:Session')->find($session->getId());
        $this->storage        = $this->UnserializeSessionData(explode('|', $record->getData())[1])['storage'];
    }

    public function renderLogo()
    {
        $logo = $this->storage->show_logo &&
        $this->storage instanceof \stdClass &&
        file_exists("/images/icons/logos/{$this->storage->prefix}_{$this->storage->host_companies_id}.gif")
            ? $this->storage->prefix.'_'.$this->storage->host_companies_id.'.gif'
            : $this->logo;

        return '<a href=""><img src="/images/icons/logos/'.$logo.'" alt="" height="60"></a>';
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
             new \Twig_SimpleFunction('render_logo', 'renderLogo', ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
        ];
    }
}
```

I am calling it from `base.html.twig` (the main layout or base template) as follow:

```
{{ render_logo() }}
```

But I end up with the following error:

> CRITICAL - Call to undefined function renderLogo()  CRITICAL -
>   Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException:
>   "Attempted to call function "renderLogo" from the global namespace."

I have the extension registered as follow in `services.yml`:

```
setup.twig_extension:
    class: CommonBundle\Twig\SetupExtension
    arguments: ['@doctrine','@session', '@zend_bridge']
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

What else I am missing here? I am using Symfony 3.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Twig extension's `getFunctions()` method you are telling Twig that the callable is the string `renderLogo`. This is interpreted by PHP as the function `renderLogo()`. For object methods, you need to pass an array where the first element is the object and the second one is the method name (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return [
         new \Twig_SimpleFunction('render_logo', [$this, 'renderLogo'], ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
    ];
}
```